# Compare all columns value to another one with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble with Pandas.
I try to compare each value of a row to another one.

In the attached link you will be able to see a slice of my dataframe.
For each date I have the daily variation of some stocks.

I want to compare each stock variation to the variation of the columns labelled 'CAC 40'.
If the value is greater I want to turn it into a Boolean 1 or 0 if lower.
This should return a dataframe filled only with 1 or 0 so I can then summarize by columns.

I have tried the apply method but this doesn't work.
It returns a `Pandas.Serie` ( attached below )

```
    def compare_to_cac(row):
        for i in row:
            if row[i] >= row['CAC 40']:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0

    data2 = data.apply(compare_to_cac, axis=1)
```

[image]

Please can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with this data (column names are not important here, only the CAC 40 one is):

```
    A   B   CAC 40
0   0   2   9
1   1   3   9
2   2   4   1
3   3   5   2
4   4   7   2
```

With just a for loop :

```
for column in df.columns:
    if column == "CAC 40":
        continue
    condition = [df[column] > df["CAC 40"]]
    value = [1]
    df[column] = np.select(condition, value, default=0)
```

Which gives me as a result :

```
    A   B   CAC 40
0   0   0   9
1   0   0   9
2   1   1   1
3   1   1   2
4   1   1   2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It has worked !!
Just a bit disapointed not to use the apply function as I am not familiar with it yet.
But anyway thank you for your answer